# Change the default color for gridview selected item in winrt application

Tags: microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to change the default color for gridview border selected item in winrt application. I try to find it in blend (item container template), but still no luck. Does anyone here know how to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer here http://labs.vectorform.com/2012/09/styling-a-gridviewitem-in-winrt/
Just change the color in the code, and you're set :)

Answer (score -1):

See if this works... :)

```
     <GridView>
        <GridView.BorderBrush>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="Red" />
        </GridView.BorderBrush>
    </GridView>
```